# Changing the default Windows language with Java application

Tags: java

Can I change the default language of my host system (Windows XP) with a Java application?
If yes, how I can do it?

Comment: You can access the Windows API through the Java Native Interface (JNI). Don't know what API functions you need to call to change the default language.

Comment: Do you mean to change the default Input Language or the default Regional Settings?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the default input language using the Windows [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.

```
BOOL WINAPI SystemParametersInfo(
  __in     UINT uiAction,
  __in     UINT uiParam,
  __inout  PVOID pvParam,
  __in     UINT fWinIni
);
```

Using [JNA](http://jna.dev.java.net) is much easier than using JNI. To invoke this API function in User32.dll using JNA, create an interface:

```
public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary
{
   User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

   bool SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, int[] pInt, int fWinIni);
}
```

You determine the LCID of the language you want to change to. ([Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h88fahh%28VS.85%29.aspx) the list from MSDN.) For example, English is 0x409. An then use the LCID in the call to `SystemParametersInfo`:

```
int lcid = 0x409;
final int SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG = 90; 
User32.INSTANCE.SystemParamtersInfo(SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG, 0, new int[] { lcid }, 0);
```

And thenn your default input language has been changed!

Answer (score 0):

There are no builtin ways provided by Java SE API. I at least see nothing in the [`Desktop`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) API. You'll need to grab OS-native API's. Forget Java for this bit, how exactly would you do this without Java? Once figured out, call the particular API using [JNI](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html) in Java.